# Can't validate checkbox value with jquery /ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my html form all data is successfully validation except checkbox value. It's not validate with jquery/ajax request.

**here is my html form ajax and html code (only terms part):**

```
<tr>
<td>Terms & Conditions</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="terms"/>&nbsp; I agree to your <a href="">terms and 
conditions</a>.</td>
```

```
<script>
  $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'regProcess.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',   
   success: function (data) {
        $('#info1').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

          $('#info1').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
        });    

   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

In regProcess.php page following is my Checkbox validation code but it's not validating..

```
if(isset($_POST['terms']) && $_POST['terms'] == ""){
    $msg[] = "You must agree our terms and conditions";
    $msg1['error'] = true;
    }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked

Comment: here you may get an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893927/send-checkbox-value-in-php-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['terms']` will not be set if it's an unchecked checkbox.  It should instead be:

```
if (empty($_POST['terms']) || $_POST['terms'] !== 'on') {
```

or just

```
if (empty($_POST['terms'])) {
```

Comment: The reason your php script isn't returning an error is because you are checking to see if `$_POST['terms']` is set, it is not.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh great you answer is working. but I don't understand why you use `on` ?

Comment: You could probably leave that out and just use `if (empty($_POST['terms'])) {` but web browsers will send the string 'on' as the value of a checked checkbox if you don't specify your own value.

Answer (score 1):

Give check box a `ID`

```
<tr>
<td>Terms & Conditions</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms"/>&nbsp; I agree to your <a href="">terms and 
conditions</a>.</td>
```

Then use this to find out checkbox is checked or not??

```
<script>
  $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#terms').is(':checked') )
  {

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'regProcess.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',   
   success: function (data) {
        $('#info1').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

          $('#info1').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
        });    

   }
  });
  }
else{
alert("Check terms and condition");
}
 });
</script>
```

## [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LrEbf/)

Comment: where i should put your code? In regProcess.php or html page ?

Comment: its jquery, so must be client side here! :)

Comment: I think he's suggesting that you not use ajax and just make sure the box is checked using javascript.

Comment: I've separate php page which process all the error an showing all error with `echo  json_encode($msg);` to html page. So now what should i do now ?

Comment: Its client side validation. using jquery. you can use serverside also