# PHP How to pass checkbox states after POST

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

I have a quick question but I seem to be having trouble locating the answer. (possibly my wording) but here goes.

- I was able to echo `POST` data from a form for the text/number
  variables without a hitch! but I am running in to a brick wall over
  these checkbox values.
- I know that if you `POST` a checkbox it will post a value of "on" but
  lets say on the form if checkbox1 is checked, how to I make a
  corresponding checkbox on the POST page load already checked?
- I know in html all you have to do is simply write "checked" within
  the code so I tried using an `if` statement to get the job done but I
  couldn't seem to get it working.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is `checked="checked"`. Can you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='selected' value='1'>
```

PHP:

```
$selected = isset($_POST['selected']) && $_POST['selected']  ? "1" : "0";
```

This code will set selected checkbox with value 1 in variable `$selected` and 0 if not selected.

Answer (score 0):

check box name will be available in post only if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (isset($_POST['myCheckbox'])) {
          $checkBoxValue = "yes";
        } else {
        $checkBoxValue = "no";
        }
```

[send checkbox value in PHP form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893927/send-checkbox-value-in-php-form)