# undefined index while submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to submit the form with empty checkbox but I want the value "no" if the checkbox is not checked.

```
if($Domain_Check=="yes")
{
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:20px;">
                Domain_Check   <input type="checkbox" name="Domain_Check1" value="yes" checked>
            </div>
         </div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:20px;">
                Domain_Check   <input type="checkbox" name="Domain_Check1" value="yes">
             </div>
          </div>';
}
```

Comment: please edit and update complete code.

Comment: actually this code is a part of php code. the domain check value is yes it will display the checked textbox otherwise it will display unchecked textbox

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893927/send-checkbox-value-in-php-form#answer-19894178

Comment: in the `else` part write `value="no"` instead of `value="yes"`

Comment: Only used form items get sent. If you want "no" to get passed you need to set defaults and then override them if the value is set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input before the checkbox to set a default value with the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Domain_Check1" value="no">
<input type="checkbox" name="Domain_Check1" value="yes">
```

The hidden input will be overridden if the checkbox is checked.